# How can I import subfolder from github repo to svelte REPL?

Tags: svelte

I've recently found a github repo with demo samples runnable in svelte REPL (according to readme).
There is repl.json file in the demo folder.
How can I import subfolder from github repo to svelte REPL ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The REPL uses `unpkg.com` to resolve packages, so if the repository content is published as an NPM package and the files you are looking for are part of the package, then you can implement it by adding a path.

E.g. if you import a Svelte store function, via e.g.

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
```

The `index` file from the `store` directory is loaded. You can see the folders and files e.g. on `unpkg` via the `/browse` path, in this case [`https://unpkg.com/browse/svelte@3.53.1/store/`](https://unpkg.com/browse/svelte@3.53.1/store/) or download the package and inspect it locally.

If you want to retrieve a file directly from GitHub, you can find a file URL via the "Raw" button in the GitHub UI or construct it yourself, e.g. the store source file would be in:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sveltejs/svelte/master/src/runtime/store/index.ts
```

Though this could *not* be imported directly, as it is TypeScript and not JS. Also, GitHub does not serve the files with the correct `Content-Type`. The REPL will still allow this as it processes the file contents internally instead of importing them directly in the resulting HTML/JS.

If the file is compatible with the REPL's build configuration, it can be imported directly, e.g. JSON works:

```js
import pkg from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sveltejs/svelte/master/package.json';
```

Otherwise you could `fetch` it and possibly process it yourself.